# hibernate console configuration cant find jdbc driver in database connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jdbc

I am trying to create POJO classes for hibernate by reverse engineering. For this I'm using Jboss Tools.
In Hibernate Console Configuration window for Database connection I click "New" button then chose MySql New Driver Definition icon from there and tried to choose every version of "MySQL JDBC Driver" from list  But at top of window it shows error **Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar.** I have right version jar for Mysql driver with Maven.
Could anybody tell what is the problem.

I use:
 - Eclipse Luna
 - Maven
 - Hibernate 4.3.6.Final
 - MySQL 5.6
 - JDBC MySQL Driver 5.1.32

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by downloading mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.tar.gz from [official mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.tar.gz)

Unzip and untar and you can find file mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar.
You can add it manually to your build path and enjoy. In my case new MySQL appeared.
[Link to screenshot](http://itmag.es/13gYh)

Comment: You welcome ^_^
If you will find better solution - let me know, please.